# The button is not working in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new in react native, i follow tutorial form youtube to create a button, but why my button is not working that cannot click, nothing happen. Any one please help me, here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, Linking, } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.body}>
      <Text>Center</Text>
      <Button title='Text Me' onPress={()=>{Linking.openURL('https://www.youtube.com')}}></Button>
    </View>
  )
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  body: {
    padding: 16,
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }
});

export default App;
```

Comment: It's working for me.

Comment: ahhhh, i just close the app then reopen it. And it's work now! Thank You